# Can use WEB HOOK in Testcafe?

Tags: testcafe

Can use Web Hook in testcafe or testcafestudio?

I want make thie

1. Run test A in testcafe or testcafestudio
2. Finish test
3. Send test result to Teams channel by use Web Hook

Comment: Hi, @ 김철수! I've noticed you have asked several similar questions about TestCafe recently, and it seems like you're just getting started with that framework. It's recommended that before asking a question here, you first take a look at the official documentation, or a good introductory tutorial, and then make an attempt to solve the problem on your own. If you get stuck, then post the specific code or API functionality you're having problems with, along with what you're trying to accomplish and why what you've tried doesn't solve your problem. This will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: In its current form, this question is too open-ended to receive the kind of detailed and specific answer that will help you implement a working solution. This is why the answers you've been getting so far are mainly links to documentation and/or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe does not have an out of the box solution for this task.

However, you can use the reportTestDone or the reportTaskDone method to create a custom Reporter (https://testcafe.io/documentation/402810/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin) that sends test execution data to a web hook. You can also learn more about community Reporters here: (https://testcafe.io/documentation/402825/guides/intermediate-guides/reporters)